# Is there an equivalent to Enigmail for Mail.app?

Tags: email, osx-snow-leopard, encryption, apple-mail

I like using Mail.app, but I'd also like to have encryption/signing options. Is there a Mail.app plugin like [Enigmail](http://enigmail.mozdev.org/home/index.php) for Thunderbird? I'm on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GPG plugin that will let you encrypt or sign messages.  http://www.sente.ch/software/GPGMail/English.lproj/GPGMail.html

Comment: I'm on Snow Leopard; I'll update the question to reflect that restriction.

Comment: You can get a version for Snow Leopard from here: http://github.com/rca/GPGMail/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Now at http://gpgtools.org (Snow Leopard compatible, Sparkle updates, all-in-one installer, ...)